# Deserialzing with javascriptserializer throws exception when found same field name

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to deserialize a json file and store the values in the variables declared in set of classes. The json file is below

```
 {
   "name"         : "sectionname",
   "section"      : 44,
   "comment"      : "Example ,
   "dimensions"   : [
      {  
         "name"      : "rtfss",
         "elements"  : 34,
         "comment"   : "sdada"
      },
 ]
}
```

I cant deserialize the json since there are two name and comment fields. How to solve this issue? I cant change the data in the json. Pls help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an object that is nested to contain the data in the `dimensions` collection.

```
public class Dimension
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int elements { get; set; }
    public string comment { get; set; }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int section { get; set; }
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public List<Dimension> dimensions { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialise the data in your Json to `MyObject`.

There are online tools like this [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/). You can give it your Json and then it will generate c# classes for you.

On a side note, the Json that you provided does have an error in it. `"Example"` is missing a closing quote mark.

Then you can use whichever serialisation tools you want to do the deserialisation.

```
var deserialisedObject = JsonConvert.Deserialise<MyObject>(jsonString);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. It works fine but sometimes there is not gonna be any dimension parameter at all. Could you help me on how to deal with that.When the dimension data is absent i get an exception again..

Comment: Hi,, Please ignore the above query..Fixed it be handling exception. have a nice day :)